# How can we add a reverb effect to exoplayer in android

Tags: android, audio, filter, media-player, exoplayer

I have used the below code to add reverb effect to exoplayer. I Don't think the effect is being applied, Can anyone help me get the audio filters applied to the video/audio played

```
val reverb =  PresetReverb(1, 0)
reverb.preset = PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL
reverb.enabled = true
simplePlayer?.setAuxEffectInfo(AuxEffectInfo(reverb.id, 1.0f))
simplePlayer?.prepare(mediaSource, true, true)
simplePlayer?.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_OFF
simplePlayer?.playWhenReady = true
```

Comment: Any further findings to that topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can add reverb effect by choosing the priority and audio session of the Audio Track. As you  want to add the reverb effect to an exoplayer instance, you should use

```
simplePlayer.audioSessionId
```

This should be done each time, when there is change in the exoplayer playback(i.e. playing of new file, change of media Item)

For applying the reverb effect

```
val reverb = PresetReverb(1, simplePlayer.audioSessionId)

reverb.preset = PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL
reverb.enabled = true
simplePlayer.setAuxEffectInfo(AuxEffectInfo(reverb.id,1f))
```

For removing the reverb effect

```
reverb.enabled=false
simplePlayer.clearAuxEffectInfo()
```

For any further help refer to [Preset Reverb](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/PresetReverb)